# It is possible to use an existing ViewController with PerformSegueWithIdentifier?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

I use the method `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` to open a new `ViewController` from a storyboard-file programmatically. This works like a charm.

But on every time when this method is being called, a new `ViewController` would be created. Is it possible to use the existing `ViewController`, if it exista? I don't find anything about this issue (apple-doc, Stack Overflow, ...).

The Problem is:
On the created `ViewController` the user set some form-Elements and if the `ViewController` would be called again, the form-elements has the initial settings :(

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit:
I appreciate the many responses. Meanwhile, I'm not familiar with the project and can not check your answers.

Comment: According to MVC pattern, you should save user values in any shared object or in NSUserDefaults. So your question is not completely right

Comment: You are right, this feature is at the moment not implemented and would come in future! This would solved my problem, but the question is still the same, if an ViewController can be reused with this method? I cant imagine that this is not possible.

Answer (score 12):

Use *shouldPerforSegueWithIdentifier* to either allow the segue to perform or to cancel the segue and manually add your ViewController. Retain a pointer in the *prepareForSegue*.

... header

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) MyViewController *myVC;
```

... implementation

```
-(BOOL) shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender{
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegueIdentifier"]){
        if(self.myVC){
            // push on the viewController
            [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.myVC animated:YES];
             // cancel segue
            return NO; 
        }
    }
    // allow the segue to perform
    return YES;
}


-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MySegueIdentifier"]){
        // this will only be called the first time the segue fires for this identifier
        // retian a pointer to the view controller
        self.myVC = segue.destinationViewController;
    }
}
```

Comment: its considered bad practice to reach up and mutate a parents state

Answer (score 8):

To reuse an existing `UIViewController` instance with a segue create the segue from scratch and provide your own (existing) destination (`UIViewController`). Do not forget to call `prepareForSegue:` if needed.

For example:

```
UIStoryboardSegue* aSegue = [[UIStoryboardSegue alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"yourSegueIdentifier" source:self destination:self.existingViewController]
[self prepareForSegue:aSegue sender:self];
[aSegue perform];
```

Comment: Where do other properties of the segue come from with this approach, such as the presentation style?

Comment: This is what UIStoryboardSegueTemplate _performWithDestinationViewController does for you, except it also retains the sender and sets UIView animationsEnabled if segue.animates is set.

Answer (score 2):

Following code makes singleton view controller.
Add them to your destination view controller implementation, then segue will reuse the same vc.

```
static id s_singleton = nil;
+ (id) alloc {
    if(s_singleton != nil)
        return s_singleton;
    return [super alloc];
}
- (id) initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if(s_singleton != nil)
        return s_singleton;
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];
    if(self) {
        s_singleton = self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: How do you handle `didReceiveMemoryWarning` with this approach ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a property for the controller.

```
@property (nonatomic, weak) MyController controller;
```

And use some kind of lazy initialization in `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender`

```
if (self.controller == nil)
{
self.controller = [MyController alloc] init]
...
}
```

In this case, if controller was already created, it will be reused.

Comment: Thanks, I had check this but it doesnt work for me. I dont know how lazy initialization works in context from the perform method?

Answer (score 0):

I faced this problem today and what I have done is to create the view controller manually and store it's reference.
Then every time I need the controller, check first if exists.
Something like this:

```
MyController *controller = [storedControllers valueForKey:@"controllerName"];

if (!controller)
{
    controller = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:NULL] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MyControllerIdentifierOnTheStoryboard"];

    [storedControllers setValue:controller forKey:@"controllerName"];
}

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, it seems that this solution will work. I solved my problem by saving the user input like d.lebedev mentioned. You push the viewcontroller with the help of the navigationController, can you use the performSegueWithIdentifier-method instead?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you would be going against Apple's design in [Using Segues](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingSegues.html): "A segue always presents a new view controller".

To understand why it might help to know that what a segue does is create a new view controller and then the perform calls either showViewController or showDetailViewController depending on what kind of segue it is. So if you have an existing view controller just call those methods! e.g.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    Event *object = [self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    [self showDetailViewController:self.detailViewController.navigationController sender:self];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You would need to make the Viewcontroller into a singleton class.